# UITableView changes its style by itself

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, xib

I face this kind of problem for the first time.

I have `UITableView` on my ViewController and I choosed `Grouped` style in the IB. 
So when I run my app on iPad, it is grouped style and everything is OK, but sometimes `UITableView's` style becomes `Plain`. I dont change it anywhere in code or something, it just changes it by itself.

**.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

**.m**

```
myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
myTableView.opaque = NO;
myTableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

I tried to delete the `XIB` and create a new one, but its still the same problem.
Any ideas?

**UPD**:

OK, I dont know how, but I got 2 same xibs in my projects with same name. And in one xib I had Plain Style and in the 2nd one I had Grouped style; so its explains why sometimes I had Grouped and somteimes Plain Style. I just deleted one of them and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Well what about the delegate methods? Please include datasource methods.Also it never happened to me.Please make sure in code there is somewhere the style not specified to change programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView style doesn't change automatically, unless you change the style either in xib or in code. Please check your code once carefully weather u are changing the style or not and also make sure that u are properly connected datasource and delegate.
Hear is the another way you can create one in the code instead in the xib. 
Create the tableview in code following code gives u some idea.

```
 @interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

 {

 UITableView *aTableVIew;
 }

@end

  @implementation ViewController


 - (void)viewDidLoad
{

  [super viewDidLoad];
  //Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

aTableVIew = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds  style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

aTableVIew.dataSource = self;
aTableVIew.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:aTableVIew];
}


 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
       [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
      //Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


  -(void)dealloc
  {
       [aTableVIew release];
       [super dealloc];
  } 

 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

   return 2;

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

   return 2;
}

  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableVIew dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(cell == nil)
{

      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];
  }
  if(indexPath.section == 0)
  {
     cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";
  }
  else if (indexPath.section == 1)
  {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"World";
  }
  else
  {
     cell.textLabel.text = @"Happy coding";
  }
  return cell;
 }

 @end
```

Comment: Thank you Shaun, I think creating UITableView programmaticaly is my best option for now. But I just can not understand, why sometimes its Grouped and after 2nd "Build and Run" it becomes Plain. And after I Build and Run the project one more time, its Grouped again. And so on - Grouped, Plain, Grouped, Plain and etc.